# Fixing request entity too large error under django/apache/mod_wsgi for file uploads

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi, django-filer

I after much gnashing of teeth found out my uploads were working just that I was getting a request entity to large 413 error I wasn't seeing.  The django app is running under apache mod_wsgi, and I am no apache guru so i am not sure what I need to set to handle larger files.  I tried to google online but it was unclear if it was a timeout issue or a file size restriction issue to me.  Also not clear if it is a setting in my settings.py file.   I currently cannot upload anything over 1MB about.  (Doesn't even sound right for all the defaults I read)  Anyone done this before and can give some insight?

Answer (score 2):

That would indicate that you have `LimitRequestBody` directive set to a very small value in the Apache configuration. This directive wouldn't normally be set at all if using standard Apache. Even if you happen to be using `mod_wsgi-express` the default there is 10MB. So it must have been overridden to a smaller value.

Comment: its strange i didnt have it at all and i did finally add it to 10mb or so and no change... i dont have the httpd.conf its at the office but I had it not in my /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf file at all...so confused still what is governing this.

Comment: For folks using mod_wsgi-express, and want to change the configuration to allow requests >10 MB, use `limit-request-body` parameter when starting the mod_wsgi_express server. Described [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/modwsgi/8Je94iXD5lQ/guLWWRiYAwAJ)